# React data flow

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a blog application and I am a bit confused on the data flow patterns of React.

Should I be trying to use something like Redux to store all of my posts after fetching the posts? Do I use local storage?

How do I then tell a component to render the 'expanded' version of the post? Is it better to re-use a 'post' component or should I just create two seperate components, one for the title and one for the full post?

I know it's two questions in one, but they kind of go together. Thanks in advance

Comment: Use Redux to store the blogs instead of local Storage. 
If you are using single Api endpoint to fetch data. then Use one dispatch function to get the entire blog post and in your `onclick` function just show the remaining post

Comment: Thanks, I just didn't want to use Redux for such a small application, but I can learn it.

Comment: `local storage` isn't meant to store blog posts. 
You don't even need redux probably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I've found out about these topics after 6 months into my self-taught React journey.

In my opinion, React built-in features are more than enough to handle `state` for a small to medium applications (especially if you're working alone as a single developer).

If you turn to Redux right away, you'll have to learn this whole new pattern of handling state in a single immutable store and how to connect your components to it.

Since you will be most likely fetching data asynchronously, you'll need a helper library to work async on Redux: `redux-thunk` or `redux-saga`.

So right from the start, you'll have to add:

- redux
- react-redux
- redux-thunk OR redux-saga

That is a lot of documentation to digest. It's perfectly doable, but I couldn't agree more with this quote:

***don't solve problems that you don't have***

It will be hard to learn those tools, since you've never faced the problems that they solve. Problems that you don't encounter just yet when you're starting to learn React.

**Read this (from Redux creator):**

https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367

---

So, my recommendation to you:

**Learn basic React (with classes):**

https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html

**Then learn React Hooks (and you can basically forget about class components):**

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Build your project using only React at first. And see how it goes. Then you can read more about Redux and what it does, and will be able to make a better choice on if you really need it or not.

---

From what you've told us about your project:

- Keep a `state` for all your posts in a component high in the tree. Maybe inside the `<App/>` component itself.
- Build your functions to fetch and update post data and update the state with the response.
- Render how many components as you wish. Displaying full info about the post inside a `BlogPostComponent` or simplified version inside a `BlogPostThumbnailCard` with just the thumbnail and the title, for example.

Comment: Awesome expanation, very thoughtful and appreciated. I was curious as to if it was a bad idea to store all of my posts in the root <App />, but I don't think it would be that bad of an idea. Is it possible to seperate data fetching into its own component then import that into the <App /> or any other component and hold the state in its own component?

Comment: Yes. For example I have a Product Page in my app that needs to fetch data about one product and display on the screen. What I usually do is to divide that page into 2 components. `ProductContainer` (which will hold the state for the product and all functions to fetch and update it) and `ProductPage` (wich will handle all the UI rendering from the props that it receives from `ProductContainer`).

Comment: Thank you so much for the amazing comment, I appreciate it!

Comment: You don't need to keep all the state inside App. Just the ones that will be needed in lots of children components in different levels in the component tree. For example: authentication state is a great candidate to be inside App. But you can have state in smaller groups of components as well. If they are the only ones that need it. Like the one I described in the comment above about the Product page.

Comment: And also if other components have been created and they need access to some local state that is currently not available to them, it's time to lift state up: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: You can upvote and select my answer as correct if you want. I'd appreciate it! Happy coding to you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be ready for the next versions of React and have a shorter code, you should try the hooks and avoid Classes

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

You can organize your code as you want, but this is more interesting to have scalability with your components and reuse them with different properties

Comment: Thanks! I use hooks and functional components rather than class based components. The way I have my posts rendering now is mapping an array and rendering the titles from each post, its difficult for me to understand how I would render just one single post out of the list rather than all of them. Thank you for your reply